# Exclude testing folder in tsconfig.lib.json (Angular Library)

Tags: angular, tsconfig, angular-library

Whenever I try to create a build. I get error. And I need to exclude a particular test folder from angular library. In tsconfig.lib.json, below compilerOption I added

`"exclude": ["src/lib/testing/*.ts"]`

But  still I face the same issue. Looks like its not excluding this file during the build. Please suggest.

Comment: Add your error in the question